# Log4j logging doesn't work on wildfly-10.1.0.Final

Tags: log4j, wildfly-10

Log4j logging doesn't work on wildfly-10.1.0.Final, even logfile is not created. Application seems to be working

my log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="File" value="/local/icm/iban-konverter/logs/iban-konverter-log.txt"/>
<param name="Encoding" value="ISO-8859-1"/>
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
<param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3"/><!-- define how many backup files to keep -->
<param name="Append" value="true"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.bsbanksysteme">
<level value="debug"/>
</logger>

<root>
<priority value ="error"/>
<appender-ref ref="console"/>
<appender-ref ref="file"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Where is your `log4j.xml` file located in your deployment?

Comment: log4j.xml is in /WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Do you have a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in your deployment? What you should see is log messages going to the server.log. Also can you execute the following CLI command and let us know the results? `/subsystem=logging:read-resource`

Comment: "add-logging-api-dependencies"=>true,
"use-deployment-logging-config"=>true,
"async-handler"=>undefined,
"console-handler"=>{"CONSOLE"=>undefined},
"custom-formatter"=>undefined,
"custom-handler"=>undefined,
"file-handler"=>undefined,
"log-file"=>{
"server.log"=>undefined,
"server.log.2017-10-23"=>undefined,
"server.log.2017-10-24"=>undefined,
}

Comment: "logger"=>{
"com.arjuna"=>undefined,
"org.jboss.as.config"=>undefined,
"sun.rmi"=>undefined
},
"logging-profile"=>{"log4j"=>undefined},
"pattern-formatter"=>{
"PATTERN"=>undefined,
"COLOR-PATTERN"=>undefined
},
"periodic-rotating-file-handler"=>{"FILE"=>undefined},
"periodic-size-rotating-file-handler"=>undefined,
"root-logger"=>{"ROOT"=>undefined},
"size-rotating-file-handler"=>undefined,
"syslog-handler"=>undefined

Comment: There you can see logging profile "log4j" which I made. I don't have any jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: This way I set the logging profile:

/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=log4j:add
/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=log4j/file-handler=iban-konverter-file:add(file={path=>"iban-konverter.log", "relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir"})

/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=log4j/file-handler=iban-konverter-file:change-log-level(level="INFO")

/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=log4j/logger=com.bsbanksysteme:add(level=DEBUG)

/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=log4j/logger=com.bsbanksysteme:assign-handler(name="iban-konverter-file")

Comment: You can't use a logging profile and use a log4j.xml file. Which one are you trying to get to work?

Comment: My idea is that use of log4j.xml file should be simplier, so I would try this. There is log4j.xm in /WEB-INF/classes, log4j-1.2.15.jar in /WEB-INF/lib. There is also a lof4j module in Wildfly... Do I need a jboss-deployment-structure? Something in /META-IINF/MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: Assuming you're using log4j loggers you should only need to include the `log4j.xml`. The module will be automatically added to your deployment so there is no need for the log4j library to be included in your deployment.

Comment: If I understand it, the application use log4j logger <logger name="com.bsbanksysteme">. I'm not sure what include of log4j.xml means. I though that place it in WEB-INF/classes is enough, isn't it?

Comment: Yes putting the log4j.xml in the WEB-INF/classes should be enough. What I meant by using log4j loggers was using `org.apache.log4j.Logger`'s in your application.